# How to add PyQt5 QtWidgets.QTabWidget() properly to sub-classed QWidget

Tags: python, qt5, pyqt5, qtabwidget

I am attempting to subclass PyQt5 QWidget and encapsulate a QTabWidget() for dynamic reuse and have run into an issue where either the Tabs do not show or they do show but their content does not show.

I think I must be missing something fundamental and am fairly new to Qt.

Here is example code where I cannot get things to show properly.

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

scriptDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))          
testImage = scriptDir + os.path.sep + 'test_tree.png'

class TabImages(QtWidgets.QWidget):        
    def __init__(self, parent):   
        super(QtWidgets.QWidget, self).__init__(parent) 
        self.container = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        # Initialize tab screen
        self.tabs = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.tab1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()

        self.tab1_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()  
        self.tab2_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()  
        self.tab3_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        self.tab1.setLayout(self.tab1_layout)
        self.tab2.setLayout(self.tab2_layout)
        self.tab3.setLayout(self.tab3_layout)

        self.tab1_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.tab2_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.tab3_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()

        self.tab1_pixMap =  QtGui.QPixmap(scriptDir + os.path.sep + 'test_image1.png')
        self.tab2_pixMap =  QtGui.QPixmap(scriptDir + os.path.sep + 'test_image2.png')
        self.tab3_pixMap =  QtGui.QPixmap(scriptDir + os.path.sep + 'test_image3.png')                

        self.tab1_label.setPixmap(self.tab1_pixMap)
        self.tab2_label.setPixmap(self.tab2_pixMap)
        self.tab3_label.setPixmap(self.tab3_pixMap)

        self.tab1_layout.addWidget(self.tab1_label)
        self.tab2_layout.addWidget(self.tab2_label)
        self.tab3_layout.addWidget(self.tab3_label)                         

        # Add tabs
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab1,"Tab 1")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab2,"Tab 2")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab3,"Tab 3")  


        self.container.addWidget(self.tabs)
        #self.tabs.show()

class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow): 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Tabbed PixMap'
        self.left = 0
        self.top = 0
        self.width = 800
        self.height = 600
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)               

        self.tabImages = TabImages(self)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()        
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabImages)
        #self.layout.addLayout(self.tabImages.container)

        self.center()
        self.show()

    def center(self):
        frameGm = self.frameGeometry()
        screen = QtWidgets.QApplication.desktop().screenNumber(QtWidgets.QApplication.desktop().cursor().pos())
        centerPoint = QtWidgets.QApplication.desktop().screenGeometry(screen).center()
        frameGm.moveCenter(centerPoint)
        self.move(frameGm.topLeft())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Note the commented out

```
tabs.show()
```

if I un-comment this the tab container shows but outside the main window.

[image]

I have also tried adding both the layout and widget but neither seem to change the behavior. I would appreciate anyone's insight.

If I were doing this same thing in a single window without trying to subclass as a new widget then I do it like this and use setCentralWidget() and it works fine

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

scriptDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))          
testImage = scriptDir + os.path.sep + 'test_tree.png'



class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow): 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Tabbed PixMap'
        self.left = 0
        self.top = 0
        self.width = 800
        self.height = 600
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)               

        # Initialize tab screen
        self.tabs = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.tab1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()

        self.tab1_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()  
        self.tab2_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()  
        self.tab3_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        self.tab1.setLayout(self.tab1_layout)
        self.tab2.setLayout(self.tab2_layout)
        self.tab3.setLayout(self.tab3_layout)

        self.tab1_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.tab2_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.tab3_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()

        self.tab1_pixMap =  QtGui.QPixmap(scriptDir + os.path.sep + 'test_image1.png')
        self.tab2_pixMap =  QtGui.QPixmap(scriptDir + os.path.sep + 'test_image2.png')
        self.tab3_pixMap =  QtGui.QPixmap(scriptDir + os.path.sep + 'test_image3.png')                

        self.tab1_label.setPixmap(self.tab1_pixMap)
        self.tab2_label.setPixmap(self.tab2_pixMap)
        self.tab3_label.setPixmap(self.tab3_pixMap)

        self.tab1_layout.addWidget(self.tab1_label)
        self.tab2_layout.addWidget(self.tab2_label)
        self.tab3_layout.addWidget(self.tab3_label)

        # Add tabs
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab1,"Tab 1")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab2,"Tab 2")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab3,"Tab 3")     

        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)
        self.center()
        self.show()


    def center(self):
        frameGm = self.frameGeometry()
        screen = QtWidgets.QApplication.desktop().screenNumber(QtWidgets.QApplication.desktop().cursor().pos())
        centerPoint = QtWidgets.QApplication.desktop().screenGeometry(screen).center()
        frameGm.moveCenter(centerPoint)
        self.move(frameGm.topLeft())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

I do not know that it makes a difference but I am running the recompiled version of PyQT5 packaged with Anaconda on a windows 10 machine.

Thanks

Comment: Note that your question has nothing to do with subclassing.  You need to add a [layout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvboxlayout.html) of some description to your widget and then add the `QTabWidget` to that layout.

Comment: I cannot understand what you want to know.How to subclass QTabWidget properly in the title,but please tell us your hoping result.Or do you want to know the defference of layout system,setCentralWidget,and parent-child relationship?

Comment: Sorry but I thought I had already a layout (self.container) in the sub-classed widget and that I had added properly the QTab to this layout. I used the QTabWidget successfully without encapsulating it in a sub-classed widget so my issue appears to be in that specific implementation. I have also added the subc-classed widget object to the main window layout by addWidget() and by addLayout() using its container layout but neither have worked in the desired way.

Comment: @Dizzixx Do you understand what is subclassing? What is subclassing for you?

Comment: Subclassing is what I did with the TabImages class in the top bit of code. It inherents the methods of QWidget by the line super(QtWidgets.QWidget, self).__init__(parent) this should allow me to use this sub class as I would a QWidget to either override its current functionality by re-defining it or add new functionality. In this example I have added functionality to the default initialization by generating a QTabWidget, tabs, tab layouts, tab contents, and the widget layouts on initialization.

Comment: @Dizzixx If you have another question that arises from this you must create a new POST, the idea of SO is to solve a particular problem, not to solve several problems in a question. please read [ask], go through the [tour] again so that you understand the SO dynamics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem arises because:

- One of the reasons why in the first image the window is outside the window is because the `self.container` has never been assigned.
- The same happens with `self.layout`.

A layout is not a widget, it is not a graphic element, it is just a class that manages the position and size of the widgets that are assigned to the widget that is assigned the same layout, so if you do not assign a layout to a specific widget this will not work.

In the case of self.layout I see that it is unnecessary since you only have one widget: self.tabImages and this can be the centralwidget, if you had more widgets you could create a new centralwidget, assign it a layout to that new central widget, and in that layout add the other widgets.

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

scriptDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))          
testImage = os.path.join(scriptDir, 'test_tree.png')

class TabImages(QtWidgets.QWidget):        
    def __init__(self, parent=None):   
        super(QtWidgets.QWidget, self).__init__(parent) 
        self.container = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        # Initialize tab screen
        self.tabs = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.tab1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()

        self.tab1_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()  
        self.tab2_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()  
        self.tab3_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        self.tab1.setLayout(self.tab1_layout)
        self.tab2.setLayout(self.tab2_layout)
        self.tab3.setLayout(self.tab3_layout)

        self.tab1_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.tab2_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.tab3_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()

        self.tab1_pixMap =  QtGui.QPixmap(os.path.join(scriptDir, 'test_image1.png'))
        self.tab2_pixMap =  QtGui.QPixmap(os.path.join(scriptDir, 'test_image2.png'))
        self.tab3_pixMap =  QtGui.QPixmap(os.path.join(scriptDir,'test_image3.png'))            

        self.tab1_label.setPixmap(self.tab1_pixMap)
        self.tab2_label.setPixmap(self.tab2_pixMap)
        self.tab3_label.setPixmap(self.tab3_pixMap)

        self.tab1_layout.addWidget(self.tab1_label)
        self.tab2_layout.addWidget(self.tab2_label)
        self.tab3_layout.addWidget(self.tab3_label)                         

        # Add tabs
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab1,"Tab 1")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab2,"Tab 2")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab3,"Tab 3")  
        self.container.addWidget(self.tabs)

class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow): 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Tabbed PixMap'
        self.left = 0
        self.top = 0
        self.width = 800
        self.height = 600
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)               

        self.tabImages = TabImages()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabImages)

        self.center()
        self.show()

    def center(self):
        frameGm = self.frameGeometry()
        screen = QtWidgets.QApplication.desktop().screenNumber(QtWidgets.QApplication.desktop().cursor().pos())
        centerPoint = QtWidgets.QApplication.desktop().screenGeometry(screen).center()
        frameGm.moveCenter(centerPoint)
        self.move(frameGm.topLeft())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Eyllanesc thank you for your reply. I was attempting to simplify things by producing the smallest problem exhibiting what I thought was the issue. I was actually trying to debug this more general Tabbed widget                                                                                               fddfdfd

Comment: @Dizzixx mmm, explain yourself better, I do not understand what you point out. In your question you point out with this method I have the separate widget, but if I use a method that does not subclassify if it works, how can I make it work subclassified? And that's what my answer answers. I do not know your other problems if you do not point them out in the question, so I'm not interested. In conclusion, does my answer solve the problem you indicate in your current question?

Comment: Sorry I dont use stack all that often and I tried to comment with code and it did not work then my comment edit timed out and it would not let me fix the mess above..... I will answer momentarily.